# How to interpret a node in decision tree with a categorical variable of more than 2 levels?

Tags: decision-tree, categorical-data

I am applying binary decision tree on a dataset containing both categorical and continues variables. One of the categorical variable is vehicle types (i.e. VT) which I encoded into five levels (VT=0,1,2,3,4). In one of the tree nodes I get VT<=3.5. How should I interpret? Does it mean if VT belongs to 0,1,2 or 3?

Comment: Yes. Because it is true for those values and false for the others. What else could it possibly mean?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Basically I though I should further split it into more levels and analyze them separately.